# AGSLocalTiledLayer is not loading the map by using .tpk file

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis

I'm working on building a simple ios app by using arcgis ios map sdk. According to the guide if we want to load the map by using **.tpk** file we have to use **AGSLocalTiledLayer** class by specifying the name of the **tpk** file as below

```
import UIKit
import ArcGIS

class ViewController: UIViewController, AGSMapViewLayerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: AGSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tiledLayer = AGSLocalTiledLayer(name: "Layers")
        self.mapView.addMapLayer(tiledLayer, withName: "BaseMap")
        self.mapView.layerDelegate = self
    }

    func mapViewDidLoad(mapView: AGSMapView!) {
        print("Loaded")
    }
}
```

But its not loading the map even though I have that Layers.tpk in the project. Can anyone notify me where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: I cracked the problem. The actual problem is with the Layer.tpk file. I used the newer one and its working...

Comment: Post your comment as an answer may be it'll be helpfull for someone else :)

Comment: Yeah man you are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times while we are using files in the project bundle need to take care such that the added file is selected for the project structure in the attribute inspector and while replacing such file when debugging care should be taken.